# AllowInvalidCertificates error after turning on XDB

Tags: xdb, xconnect, docker

After turning on XDB in a Docker installation after upgrading from 9.0 u2 to 10.1.1. I get the following error. XDB works fine in a vanilla install using the same license. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: can you check if you have the right dll and the existing one is for version 10.1.1 ?

Comment: @VladIobagiu I checked Sitecore.ReferenceData.Client.Xmgmt.dll version 6. I don't have a reference to it in the project. I checked the install files and they seem to match. Unless I should be looking at a different dll.

Comment: Use the right certificate thumbnail on the apps instead of turning off certificate validation

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<add key="AllowInvalidClientCertificates" value="true" />` to the appsettings section fixed the issue.